# t902: Additional buttons - how to use them?

Tags: kernel, 13.10, button, fujitsu-siemens

I have a Fujitsu T902 and have several problems. I guess I'll split them up into different questions. I have installed 13.10 Ubuntu, uname -a tells me:

> 3.11.0-13-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 07:38:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

First of all, I have on the screen additional buttons, in total 6:

1. Win-Button
2. Vol-
3. Vol+
4. Copy (or similar symbol)
5. A
6. B

I googled and found http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2014093.html and have some questions:

When I run xev|grep keycode I get only for 1, 5 and 6 a response:

```
state 0x0, keycode 161 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x0, keycode 161 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x0, keycode 186 (keysym 0x1008ff79, XF86ScrollDown), same_screen YES,
state 0x0, keycode 186 (keysym 0x1008ff79, XF86ScrollDown), same_screen YES,
state 0x0, keycode 185 (keysym 0x1008ff78, XF86ScrollUp), same_screen YES,
state 0x0, keycode 185 (keysym 0x1008ff78, XF86ScrollUp), same_screen YES,
```

So, how to assign the (already recognized) buttons to an action? e.g. to minimize all, change volume, or similar?
Is there a chance to the 2, 3 and 4 running? If so, how?